# Which lisp implementations allow me to modify code at runtime?

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp, self-modifying

Lisp is homoiconic, meaning code can be treated as data. Which implementations allow me to do so at runtime? The following is an example of what I mean, in pseudocode:

```
(defun (my-func)
  (display "foo ")
  (display "bar ")
  (display "baz "))

(defun (main-loop)
  (my-func)
  (swap (first my-func) (second my-func))
  (main-loop))
```

That should repeatedly output "foo bar baz bar foo baz ".

Comment: I don't know of a specific implementation - but look for ones that do not compile when they evaluate. So that would exclude SBCL for instance (and probably plenty of modern Common Lisp implementations).

Comment: basically a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914779/levels-of-homoiconicity

Comment: @verdammelt: see http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Interpreter

Comment: It's not a complete duplicate as I'm specifically asking for implementations. Now I know it's possible in CLisp and probably in SBCL.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I stand corrected - thanks!

Comment: @LogicChains: basically most Lisp implementations with an Interpreter can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant approach, but in common Lisp you can do something like this:

```
> (setq f '(defun foo () (princ "foo ") (princ "bar ") (princ "baz ")))
(DEFUN FOO NIL (PRINC "foo ") (PRINC "bar ") (PRINC "baz "))
> (eval f)
FOO
> (foo)
foo bar baz
NIL
> (defun frot ()
        ; Call foo (stored in f)
        (funcall (eval f))
        ; Swap the 1st and 2nd statements in foo
        (setf tmp (cadddr f))
        (setf (cadddr f) (cadr (cdddr f)))
        (setf (cadr (cdddr f)) tmp)))
FROT
> (frot)
foo bar baz
(PRINC "foo ")
> (frot)
bar foo baz
(PRINC "bar ")
> (frot)
foo bar baz
(PRINC "foo ")
```

This stores a Lisp function in `f` rather than executing it *in situ*, but it does illustrate the fact that a Lisp program is itself a Lisp data structure than can be dynamically manipulated and executed.

Comment: Given that you're not actually extracting the source from `FOO` here, but just storing the source in `F` and evaluating it to define the function -- can't you do this in any implementation of Common Lisp? (Also, note that there's an unmatched close parenthesis at the end of your `frot` defun form.)

Comment: @svk I would think so, as it is fairly vanilla ANSI Lisp. I had, however, only verified its behavior on Clisp and sbcl. Both of those worked, with a warning from sbcl about the assignment to `f`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers cover the question well.

From a practical level however if you are using Common Lisp and Slime and want to be able to compile code into your running program from Emacs you will need to tell Swank to update from inside your loop.

Add the following to your code and then add **(update-swank)** inside your loop.

```
(defmacro continuable (&body body)
  `(restart-case
       (progn ,@body)
     (continue () :report "Just Continue")))

(defun update-swank ()
  "Called from within the main loop, this keep the lisp repl working"
  (continuable
    (let ((connection (or swank::*emacs-connection*
                         (swank::default-connection))))
      (when connection
        (swank::handle-requests connection t)))))
```

This is one way to use the fact you can recompile live with your editor [as in this video](http://youtu.be/6pMyhrDcMzw) *(sorry for plugging my own vid)*.

Another way (again with Slime) is to tell it to use a different thread for the communication. I prefer the former method however as opengl is very unstable when used across threads.

**[More Details]**
The continuable macro in the code above catches any error and gives you the option to ignore it and continue. I find this really helpful and I often make mistakes in the repl and I don't want to 'abort' from an error as this would abort my main loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are modifying code as you describe, then you know something about the structure of the code.  Since you know the structure of the code, you can parameterize that structure

```
(define (foo-er foo bar baz)
  (lambda ()
     (display foo)
     (display bar)
     (display baz)))
```

Then you can do the swapping by explicitly passing your arguments as:

```
(define (main-loop)
  (let looping ((foo "foo ") (bar "bar ") (baz "baz "))
    ((foo-er foo bar baz))
    (looping bar foo baz)))

> (main-loop)
foo bar baz bar foo baz foo bar baz ...
```

The CommonLisp version is analogous.

If you need to keep `my-func` around:

```
(define my-func #f)
(define (main-loop)
  (let looping ((foo "foo ") (bar "bar ") (baz "baz "))
    (set! my-func (foo-er foo bar baz)
    (my-func)
    (looping bar foo baz)))
```